# Will mobs despawn when moved by water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am working on a big project where I need to move mobs pretty far using a water system. They wont see light at all.

Will they despawn after some time?

Im guessing the tour will take about 3-4 mins.

Answer (score 9):

It depends if the [following conditions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Despawning) are met:

> Monsters and squid (but not animals) can spontaneously cease to exist,
> or "despawn", under certain conditions:
>
> - A mob will immediately despawn
>   if ever there is no player within 128 blocks of it.
> - A mob that has had
>   no player within 32 blocks of it for more than 30 seconds has a 1 in
>   800 chance of despawning on each game tick (1/20th of a second). That
>   means that such a mob will survive for just under a minute, on
>   average, from the time they spawned or were last within 32 blocks of a
>   player.
> - All hostile mobs in a world will despawn if the difficulty is
>   set to peaceful, regardless as to where the player is positioned in
>   the world.
>
> In multiplayer, despawning does not occur while there are
> no players in the game.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: No
Long Answer: Maybe, depending on where *you* are.

Mobs Despawn when they are a certain distance from the player, so if the water moves them far enough away from you, then yes they will despawn.
The Minecraft [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn) states that:

- A mob will immediately despawn if ever there is no player within 128 blocks of it.
- A mob that has had no player within 32 blocks of it for more than 30 seconds has a 1 in 800 chance of despawning on each game tick (1/20th of a second). That means that such a mob will survive for just under a minute, on average, from the time they spawned or were last within 32 blocks of a player.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of survival for a mob with a player in 32 - 128 blocks distance for 3 minutes is around 1%. Just did the math assuming despawn occurence independence.